# Clear old sprite when draw after resize popup or browser in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

Currently, i have drawing bar chart. My chart will redraw if change width of component. I have using invalidateProperties() and invalidateDisplayList() for bar when redraw, it has redraw with new bar is correctly.

However when resize popup or browser, my chart will be override between new bar(when redraw with new width) and old bar.

Maybe cause, it's not clear old bar when resize popup or browser. I still using (chart as Sprite).graphics.clear(), but this code not execute.

How clear the old sprite, everyone ?

Comment: Size things with percentages?

Comment: ya, percent with application for browser or group for popup when i'm config to component. Ex: `width="{this.width - 60}"`

Comment: Are you sure it's not being executed? What are you using to check if the window resizes?

Comment: yes. For test, i'm setting application width to 100% and chart component with `width="{this.width - 60}` then i resize browser